# Spring Security - Tomcat : issue with disconnection

Tags: tomcat, spring-security

I am developping a web application using Spring Security, the server is Tomcat.

If there is no activity during a long time (>30 min for example) on the webapp I am getting disconnected.
Is there a way to avoid this disconnection?

Thanks

Comment: You mean your session expires?

Comment: I guess so. I need to log again in order to use the web app. I don't know how Spring Security manages this.

Answer (score 0):

The session will timeout after a certain time of inactivity and the user will then be logged out. For Tomcat I think it is 30 minutes. You can keep the session alive by "pinging" the server at a certain interval, say like every 10 minutes. With JavaScript and jQuery:

```javascript
function setPingTimeout() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.get('ping', function() {
            setPingTimeout();
        });
    }, 600000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setPingTimeout();
});
```

Server-side can be a no-op, with Spring MVC:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/ping")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void ping() { }
```